# Spring CLI generates unexpected project structure

Tags: spring

When I generate a project with the webpage https://start.spring.io/ and with the configuration: ["group: com.foo", "artifact: bar", "build: maven", "spring boot version: 1.4.2"] I get the following project structure:

```
folder-name/
|-- mvnw
|-- mvnw.cmd
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
    |-- main
    |     |-- java
    |     |     |-- com
    |     |           |-- foo
    |     |                 |--BarApplication.java
    |     |-- resources
    |           |-- application.properties
    |-- test
          |-- java
                |-- com
                      |-- foo
                            |--BarApplicationTests.java
```

And when I generate a project with the Spring CLI command:
"spring init -g=com.foo -a=bar -name=bar --build=maven foo-bar" I get the following project structure:

```
folder-name/
|-- mvnw
|-- mvnw.cmd
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
    |-- main
    |     |-- java
    |     |     |-- com
    |     |           |-- example
    |     |                 |--BarApplication.java
    |     |-- resources
    |           |-- application.properties
    |-- test
          |-- java
                |-- com
                      |-- example
                            |--BarApplicationTests.java
```

Whatever config I use with Spring CLI. I always get the folder structure "src/java/{top-level domain}/example".
Why is the folder after the top-level domain always named "example", how do I avoid this so that it uses the group and artifact properly so that I get: "src/java/{group's top-level domain}/{group's domain}"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the --package-name parameter solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `-a` and `-g` are not correct spring cli params. Only `name` works fine.

Please referr to [How do I use the Paremeters listed in `spring init --list`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3709).